# Как получить инфо о видео через exec() с помощью ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Нашел такой код, получаю `array(0) { }`

```
<?

    exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/d/plush/public_html/video.mp4', $output);

    var_dump($output);

?>
```

Как правильно получить длительность видео и его разрешение?

Comment: Прочитайте описание функции `exec`  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php  Вторым параметром можно задать массив в который поместится вывод программы

Comment: @Mike поправил, массив пустой на выходе.

Comment: Нашелся у меня ffmpeg, оказалось он на stderr все выдает, ответ написал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg выдает информацию о файле не на стандартный вывод (`stdout`, дескриптор 1), а на вывод ошибок (`stderr`, дескриптор 2). Поэтому надо использовать перенаправление вывода ошибок на `stdout` средствами shell (`2>&1`):

```
<?php
 exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i 1.avi 2>&1', $output);
 $duration=""; $resol="";
 foreach ($output as $s):
   if(preg_match('/Duration: ([0-9:.]+)/',$s,$m)) $duration=$m[1];
   if(preg_match('/, (\d{3,4}x\d{3,4}) /',$s,$m)) $resol=$m[1];
 endforeach;
 print("Duration: $duration Resolution: $resol\n");
?>
```

Comment: Вот оно что. Нужная мне информация всегда будет под 19, 20 ключом массива, имеется в виду разрешение и продолжительность ролика? Может у вас есть готовое решение чтобы выдернуть ее из строки?

Comment: @Plush Вот в этом я бы не был уверен, у меня в тестовом примере он выдал только 17 строк, точно зависит от версии ffmpeg и наверняка зависит от конкретного видеофайла. Как у вас выглядят выдаваемые строки с нужной инфой ?

Comment: Вот они: `Duration: 00:01:25.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 326 kb/s`     
—— `Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 176x144 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], 268 kb/s, 18 fps, 18 tbr, 18 tbn, 18 tbc`

Comment: Да вы правы, ключи будут меняться, еще вариант `Duration: 00:00:28.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1634 kb/s"` ——  `Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1440 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc"`

Comment: @Plush Написал в ответе разбор. Регулярка под разрешение предполагает что сторона изображения состоит из 3-4 цифр, если у вас что то совсем мелкое встречается может стоит сделать 2-4. И мне она не очень нравится, слишком простая, как бы ложных срабатываний не было. в принципе можно еще в конец добавить `\[SAR` но надо быть уверенным что там всегда SAR а не что то другое

Comment: Только используйте ffprobe: http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html